# Update headerRight insdie my screen component

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am developing a react-native project.

I want to update my `headerRight` inside my screen component. Basically, I want to hide the header right button. I tried two options:

**Option 1,** directly update navigation options & set `headerRight` to `null` :

```
 const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
   navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: null,
    });
}
```

It works, the header right button is invisible now but I get warning:

`Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.`

**Option 2**, wrap the option 1 code inside a useEffect() hook:

```
 const MyScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
   useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: null,
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
}
```

There is no warning, the code doesn't have any effect either, the right header button is not hidden at all.

So, what is the best way to update my header right inside a screen component?

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is the right way to do it. From the docs on `headerRight`:

> Function which returns a React Element to display on the right side of the header.

Changing the value to a function should fix the issue.

```js
const MyScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => null,
    });
  }, [navigation]);
};
```

It is also important to keep in mind that in the React Navigation lifecycle the screen may remain mounted on the stack when navigating away and back to it and you may need to adjust or even remove the dependency array in order to correctly keep the header in sync with the screen.